# Scope of JavaScript variables (XUL-related)

Tags: javascript, xul

A beginner's question, probably a trivial one. Here's the XUL code snippet:

```
<window
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://.../main.js"/>

    <button label="Click me!" oncommand="clickhandler()"/>
</window>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
// main.js

var test = "Peanut butter";    // a global variable

function clickhandler() {
    alert(test);
}
```

The interpreter processes the JavaScript file just after reading the main window's opening tag and then proceeds with the rest of XUL code. In my opinion, the `test` variable should go out of scope in the very moment the interpreter finishes processing `main.js`. Moreover, the `clickhandler()` function should have gone out of scope too, which means, when the button is clicked, nothing should happen. Well, unless I declare them as `document.test` and `document.clickhandler()`, for instance. However, a simple experiment proved me wrong. Both the function and the variable exist when the button is clicked. What is the actual life span of variables declared like this? When are they destroyed? Are they around until the application exits? Any best practices and references are highly appreciated.

Comment: Some good references here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691/javascript-best-practices. Anything outside of a function and without a "var" will be defined in the "window" namespace (e.g. window.test, window.clickhandler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting it to behave like languages you are used to with block scope. I suggest reading through Douglas Crockford's book "The Good Parts" to get a better understanding of why everything works the way it does. If you learn all of this from the start you will have a much easier time down the road.

Javascript is functionally scoped.. in this example test is scoped inside of foo.

```
var foo = function() {
    var test = "Peanut Butter";
};
```

In this example, you can see that the function can modify test as it's a globally scoped variable.

```
var test = "peanut butter";
var foo = function() {
    test = "Apple sauce";
};
```

There are three ways to define globally scoped variables, all of which I would suggest you avoid (not entirely, that's impossible). Global variables are necessary, however they can be mitigated. Their lifetime is as long as the javascript is loaded. If you define multiple global variables in different .js files that are loaded by the same page, those global variables are accessible by both, making it quite easy to accidentally overwrite vars from different files.

1: Place a var statement outside of any function, like you have done.

2: Add it as a property to the global object.

```
window.foo = value;
```

3. use a variable without declaring it, this is an implied global. Really watch out for these. The function you declared is actually an implied global itself called "clickhandler".

```
foo = value;
```

A common practice to minimize the use of global variables is known as Global Abatement, in which you define an application specific global variable to hold the rest of your global variables, to avoid collision with other libraries. This is done by declaring an object literal and using the 2nd method of creating global variables. Only use this when you need global variables however, and try to stick to functional scope when possible.

```
var AWESOMENEWAPP = {};
AWESOMENEWAPP.test = "Peanut Butter";
```

When you get deeper in to the world of javascript, you'll start learning about useful things like closures and more to keep your code clean and organized.

Just don't expect javascript to work like your typical classical languages and you'll find that it is a powerful language in its own right, just different.

On your journey, I suggest using the tool [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com) to test your code for following conventions and errors you won't see because it isn't compiled.

Comment: _"Their lifetime is as long as the page exists."_ XUL apps' native look deceived me so much that I forgot they are 'pages' in essence. Does this mean that if I have more toplevel windows, there's no way to create a really global variable (shared among them), apart from using XPCOM objects?

Comment: I have never actually used XUL, so I'm not sure to be honest... If you want to share data between different windows, however, the best way to do it currently (IMO) is the web messaging api, where you send a message to the other windows to share data, and have a handler that knows it may receive the message and what to do with it.. Again, haven't used XUL apps, and don't know exactly what you are trying to do, so it's hard to say what would be best for you.

Comment: I guess a better way to put it, is the lifetime is as long as the javascript is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, global functions and variables exist until the user leaves the application or closes that tab if you are using a browser. That is why it is best practice to try not to flood your global scope with variables or functions if possible.