# jQuery values set in $(document).ready() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I want to set values for objects after the DOM has loaded completely. Problem is, I'm getting a null pointer exception after calling a `OnBlur` and `OnFocus` event from a textbox. What am I doing wrong?

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sumThursdayHrs = $('span[id*="lblThursdayHrs"]').last()
});

var tempThursdayHrs = 0.0;
function BlurThursdayHrs(sender, args) { sumThursdayHrs.text(tempThursdayHrs + sender.get_value()); }
function FocusThursdayHrs(sender, args) { tempThursdayHrs = sumThursdayHrs.text() - sender.get_value(); }
```

markup:

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtThursdayHrs" runat="server" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="1"
        Width="25px" MinValue="0" Type="Number" DbValue='<%# Eval("ThursdayHrs") %>'>
        <ClientEvents OnBlur="BlurThursdayHrs" OnFocus="FocusThursdayHrs" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'sumThursdayHrs' is undefined

Comment: Are you sure that $('span[id*="lblThursdayHrs"]') is selecting anything?

Comment: @Andrey, yes I tested in google chrome's console

Comment: @Engineer, both are client-side... the two methods are events defined in the markup, they are used in Telerik's UI framework for ASP.NET AJAX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in the heading, the values are set *in a function* (the ready-event-handler function). But JavaScript has function scope, and as you declared `sumThursdayHrs` to be a local (not to say "private") variable by using the `var` keyword, it is undefined from outside. Two possibilites:

- Make sumThursdayHrs a global variable (remove "var") (and eventually declare it outside). Note that global variables should be avoided where possible to preclude naming conflicts and co
- or take all functions using it into the same scope. Watch out, then these function will also be no more globally available so you need to set the blur/focus handlers in the same context (as Patrick Scott suggested).

Comment: Please note that you are creating an implied global variable, and although this works, it is bad coding practice. Global variables should be avoided, but if I can't stop you from doing so, at least follow my advice on Global Abatement and see this answer for more info on global variable scope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096504/scope-of-javascript-variables-xul-related/10096806#10096806

Comment: for the first suggestion that is (removing var)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using jquery already why not bind the events with jquery?

```
$('span[id$="txtThursdayHrs"]:first').on("focus", FocusThursdayHrs)
          .on("blur", BlurThursdayHrs);
```

Also, declare those function inside the doc ready function, so they can access `sumThursdayHrs`, or use anonymous functions in the same place instead of calling the functions

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sumThursdayHrs = $('span[id*="lblThursdayHrs"]').last();
    var tempThursdayHrs = 0.0;
    $('span[id$="txtThursdayHrs"]:first').on("focus", function() {
        sumThursdayHrs.text(tempThursdayHrs + $(this).val());
    })
    .on("blur", function() {
        tempThursdayHrs = sumThursdayHrs.text() - $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Or move `sumThursdayHrs` to a global object... For sanity's sake, I recommend not putting it in window though.

Instead define a global namespace to hold your app specific global variables. This is called global abatement.

Ex.

```
var MyApp = {};
$(document).ready(function () {
    MyApp.sumThursdayHrs = $('span[id*="lblThursdayHrs"]').last();
    //...
```

--

```
MyApp.tempThursdayHrs = 0.0;
function BlurThursdayHrs(sender, args) { MyApp.sumThursdayHrs.text(MyApp.tempThursdayHrs + sender.get_value()); }
function FocusThursdayHrs(sender, args) { MyApp.tempThursdayHrs = MyApp.sumThursdayHrs.text() - sender.get_value(); }
```

Comment: binding client events to complex server side controls can be very complicated

Comment: +1 right approach, but `BlurThursdayHrs`/`FocusThursdayHrs` will not see `sumThursdayHrs` until they are defined inside the document ready handler.

Comment: @Andrey he is doing that anyway, just with teleriks syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to scoping:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // sumThursdayHrs is a *local* variable to the function
    var sumThursdayHrs = $('span[id*="lblThursdayHrs"]').last()
});

// ... so this will fail because it is trying to use
// window.sumThursdayHrs (the property sumThursdayHrs on the window object),
// which is not set and thus the Reference Error
function BlurThursdayHrs(sender, args) {
    sumThursdayHrs.text(tempThursdayHrs + sender.get_value());
}
```

The "simple fix" (which may or may not be valid) is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Set the "global variable" sumThursdayHrs
    // "window." isn't technically required, but it is to show a point.
    window.sumThursdayHrs = $('span[id*="lblThursdayHrs"]').last()
});
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that code example you gave are in the same bag or not but if you've defined a variable inside the `$(document).ready()`, know that the variable is inside a closure. Outside of it, it'll be undefined.

So why not do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sumThursdayHrs = $('span[id*="lblThursdayHrs"]').last();

    var tempThursdayHrs = 0.0;

    function BlurThursdayHrs(sender, args) {
        sumThursdayHrs.text(tempThursdayHrs + sender.get_value());
    }

    function FocusThursdayHrs(sender, args) {
        tempThursdayHrs = sumThursdayHrs.text() - sender.get_value();
    } 
});
```

In the above code, it should pick up the value you intended because everything is inside the `$(document).ready()` closure. And in addition, you've assigned a jquery object, `$('span[id*="lblThursdayHrs"]')`, into a variable, so it must be used inside the jquery environment not outside... In 1 word, if you're using jquery then keep it in jquery environment.

What you did is, you've signed a contract with jquery that you'll be using all its methods and properties by doing `var sumThursdayHrs = $('span[id*="lblThursdayHrs"]').last()`. Once you use `$(something)`, that's it, it must be used inside the jquery environment.