# Why is this function not working?

Tags: javascript

I had this code:

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iFrame");
var auto_resize_timer = window.setInterval("autoresize_frames()", 400);
function autoresize_frames() {
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i) {
        if (frames[i].contentWindow.document.body) {
            var frames_size = frames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
            if (document.all && !window.opera) {
                frames_size = frames[i].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
            }
            frames[i].style.height = frames_size + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

That was working fine.

Then, I decided to put it in its own module:

```
function autoResizeFrames() {
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iFrame");
    window.setInterval("autoresize_frames(frames)", 400);
}

function autoresize_frames(frames) {

    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i) {
        if (frames[i].contentWindow.document.body) {
            var frames_size = frames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
            if (document.all && !window.opera) {
                frames_size = frames[i].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
            }
            frames[i].style.height = frames_size + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

And run it in the page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready
(
     function () {
         autoResizeFrames();
     }

    );

</script>
```

But now it does not work? Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: "does not work" how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run:

```
    window.setInterval("autoresize_frames(frames)", 400);
```

You are essentially `eval`ing your code in the context of the window.  When using setInterval, you should pass a reference to the function instead of a string.  You can read why eval is bad at [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Normally you would do:

```
    window.setInterval(autoresize_frames, 400);
```

However if your function takes arguments then you will need to wrap it in a function.

The following will work:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  autoresize_frames(frames);
}, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your own function, "frames" is declared internally.
You could try removing the "var" keyword so it becomes a global variable.

Comment: I wouldn't advise polluting the global namespace as the solution.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691/javascript-best-practices/39970#39970

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might on `frames` variable which might not be accessible inside setInterval. You can try this

```
function autoResizeFrames() {
    window.setInterval(function(){
         autoresize_frames(document.getElementsByTagName("iFrame"))
    }, 400);
}
```